# composer -V don't work with Composer in CMD windows 10

Tags: php, windows, cmd, composer-php

I have a problem executing the next line in windows 10 CMD

```
composer -V
```

the problem is that nothing happens, the command and the cmd does not do anything, I do not know what it can be, annex image

**Problem:**

```
C:\Users\José Padrón>composer -V

C:\Users\José Padrón>
```